# Is it appropriate to ask to check exercises from Dragon Book here?

Tags: discussion

I am studying the Dragon Book about compilers and it has exercises which I try to solve. Unfortunately, there is no-one nearby who could check my solutions. Is it appropriate to post my solutions here asking someone experienced to check them?

Some of the exercises do not require writing code (like this):

> Exercise 2.2.1:
> Consider the context-free grammar `S -> S S + | S S * | a`
>
> a) Show how the string aa+a* can be generated by this grammar.
> b) Construct a parse tree for this string.
> c) What language does this grammar generate? Justify your answer.

**Example of the answer**

> a) Show how the string aa+a* can be generated by this grammar.

1. Let `S1 = a` according to the 3-rd production.
2. From the 1-st production we get: `S2 -> S1 S1 + => S2 = aa+`
3. From the 2-nd production: `S3 -> S2 S1 * => S3 = aa+a*`

We got the required string `S3` using the rules of the grammar.

I asked the same question at https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/10944/edit and was sent here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better place could be the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), but you should read [their Help Center](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help) and consider asking on [their Meta site](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/) as well to confirm their policies and expectations for a question. Checking out [Programming Language Design and Implementation Stack Exchange](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/) (and their [Help Center](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/help) and [Meta site](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/)) may also be a good idea.

Topics like formal languages, automata theory, language design, and compiler design are closer to computer science than software engineering. Although the languages and tools that are the result of these theories and research are used by software engineers, this seems to be more on the theoretical and mathematical underpinnings rather than the application of these ideas to solve problems and effect change in the world.